Full references not displaying in optica publishing latex file
I am using the latex file downloaded from Overleaf (Optica publishing group) if I run
in Overleaf, the whole reference displays, however, when I download it and run it with
TeXstudio list of fullreference not displaying.
I tried with the given below code for class files. However, it is not working. we have separate files for the bibliography.
    \documentclass[9pt,twocolumn,twoside]{opticajnl}

\journal{ol} % Choose journal (ao,jocn,josaa,josab,ol,optica,pr)
\setboolean{shortarticle}{true}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
 %\title{Unveiling a Pioneering Approach}
\title{Liquid Drop Interferometry on Reflective Surfaces}
 \author[1]{AA Verma}
\affil[1]{AAAA}


\begin{abstract}
We resolve the main bottleneck of achieving optimal fringe 
contrast on surface, the need for a reference lens with a specific 
coating is eliminated........ 
\end{abstract}

\setboolean{displaycopyright}{true}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

 %\section{Introduction}
   In recent advancements aimed at enhancing precision \cite{Apl1} in measuring.....


 \bibliography{sample}
  \bibliographyfullrefs{sample}

        @article{Apl1,
       author = "Verma, Gopal and Singh, Kamal P.",
        title = "Time-resolved interference unveils nanoscale 
      surface dynamics in evaporating sessile droplet",
    journal = "Applied Physics Letters",
    year = "2014",
    volume = "104"
                 }


If you literally did as you say, it is not surprising it doesn't work. Please provide a small but complete file we can use to reproduce the problem. But the most likely reason is that you haven't run bibtex. You need to run that and then compile at least twice more for references to show up. Overleaf does this for you. TeX Studio doesn't.

you need pdflatex then bibtex then pdflatex twice more. (overleaf does that for you)

probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number

@cfr, I tried however still it is not displaying Full references, Even  \bibliographyfullrefs{sample} command shows that it is an unrecognized command in TeXstudio.

Where did you get opticajnl.cls? That's not a standard class. Is that what provides \bibliographyfullrefs? That's not a standard command. I assumed the class provided it, but if it says it is undefined? Usually you'd have \bibliographystyle{...} and \bibliography{...}.

What happened when you ran bibtex?

@cfr, I downloaded it (opticajnl.cls) from Overleaf, where it displays full references. Yes, I tried Bibtex, however, it is not working.

Can you post the log files from compiling the example in your question? There should be one .log from running pdflatex and one from running bibtex. (I think .blg? - it's a long time since I ran bibtex.) Post a link for the Overleaf class or template.

@cfr, This is the link to Overleaf  (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/universal-manuscript-template-for-optica-publishing-group-journals/ybkgndgdxpzy) I downloaded the zip file and tried to run in teTtstuido, However, fullreference list is not displaying. You can first check in overleaf.
